# Alternatives to arxiv

Tags: education, publishing

I am an amateur mathematician (but I do have degree's in computer science (with mathematics)). Anyways, I have written this paper, where I have proved that for $\zeta(\rho) = 0$ if $\Im(\rho) \to \infty$ then $\Re(\rho) \leq \log_2(3) - 1$.

Now this is a big claim, and I am a cranky fella ;) who has a number of withdrawn papers on arxiv. So, chances of me being taken seriously $\to 0$ even though I do put my sweat in for checking any paper I write, before releasing it.

So, the problem is how do I get my paper discussed and verified, before I put it on arxiv (cause I do not want to withdraw it again) and also I do not know any local mathematician working on analytic number theory.
So here's my question:

> Before posting on arxiv are there any
>   other avenues through which I can get
>   my paper checked (on the internet)?

Comment: This should be community wiki.

Comment: Submit it to a journal directly.

Comment: @Agustí: not always an option, since you can wait a long time for a response, especially now that it's "summer recess".

Comment: This would be more appropriate for academia.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are other places to post papers, but most are either harder to get into (most online journals) or are less reputable than the arXiv (like viXra).  Finding math forums and posting there may be your best bet.

- http://mymathforum.com/
- http://mersenneforum.org/
- http://physicsforums.com/

to name just a few.

---

On this specific point:

Your result seems wrong.  Aren't there vertical asymptotes and, in particular, values unbounded above for $\Re(\zeta(x+iy))$ for any fixed $y$?

If you have (or think you have) an *effective* proof, can you give bounds Y and Z > 0 where, for any $y>Y$, $\Re(\zeta(x+iy)) < Z$?

Comment: Thanks both of you... Charles and Jyotirmoy... I accept Charles' answer because its more of what I wanted to hear... :)

Comment: Physicsforums does not allow people to post their own original research.

Answer (score 10):

No one on the internet (or elsewhere) is obliged to check your paper. So you have to catch people's interest and minimize the amount of investment they have to make.

Here are some suggestion based not on personal experience but from being an spectator round the Net:

1. Make your work easy to understand: Present your work in a theorem-lemma format, clearly specifying links to existing literature and pinpointing your own specific contributions.
2. Make your work publicly accessible: Put it up on you website. Or on Google Documents. Or on http://vixra.org
3. Publicise the key points: Make a newsgroup posting, or create a question here or on Mathoverflow that explains your main insight or innovation and link to your paper.

I was a bit hesitant in writing (3) since if you do it wrong you are just creating spam. No one is obliged to read on if you say "I have proved X. Can you please check?". Much better to say "So far people did not succeed in approach A to problem B because of C. But I think things can be made to work if you do D. Here's an attempt."

Comment: The "newsgroup" posting part is likely not going to help too much. I know that I (and judging from the responses I've seen on `sci.math`, many other users) make a habit of ignoring posts of the form "I've proven X which is related to big conjecture Y, can you check?" It is nothing personal, having rather to do with the average signal-to-noise ratios on those types of threads (even when you have an honest result and make an honest question out of it, the thread will often be swamped by cranks).